# using email addresses as keys in firestore

Tags: google-cloud-firestore

I want to create "invitations" based on email addresses so that when a user with that email would arrive to the system his invitations would already be waiting for him.

so I wanted to create an invitations collection with key based on `groupId + '_' + invited_user_email` but if the user is `test@test.com` this the `.com` is interpreted as a subkey :(

I tried `groupId + '_' + invited_user_email.replace(/[.]/g,'\\.')` but it did not help either.

What am I missing? Is there no way to include a '.' in a firestore document's ID ?

EDIT:
per Doug Stevenson's request here is the code I use now:

```
     var invitedUserEmailAsKey=invitedUserEmail.replace(/[.]/g,'\\.')
     var batch = db.batch();

     var groupRef = db.collection("groups").doc(groupId);
     var invitationRef = db.collection("invitations").doc( groupRef.id + '_' + invitedUserEmailAsKey);

     var groupUpdates = {};
     groupUpdates['invited.' + invitedUserEmailAsKey + '.user_name'] = invitedUserName;
     groupUpdates['merge'] = true;

     batch.update(groupRef, groupUpdates);
```

The problems are with the updated document on the groups collection.
It ends up looking like this:
[image]

instead of having someone@gmail.com as a key

Comment: I have no problems creating documents with a period in the id.  Can you edit the question to show the exact code and error message you're seeing?

Comment: @DougStevenson Hello Firebaser! I've had a use case where the docID is an email-id. Ended up using your suggestion and using string.replace(".", "\\.") and it works fine. It displays as a single field with every "." replaced by "\." in the console unlike in the above screenshot. Although it would be awesome if no workaround was required, thanks for the workaround!  :P

Answer (score 0):

Using update() with "dot" in a key is interpreted as a nested field as [documented here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#update_fields_in_nested_objects).

Notice that you're updating a document fields (groupRef) and not really doing anything with the "invitations" collection. I don't think that creating a new field on the group doc for every invitation is what you really mean to do.

Comment: It is still work in progress. I am also creating an invitations collection which works just fine with document key being groupId_userEmail and document fields being groupId, groupName, userEmail & userName to allow for both list of invitations to group and list of invitations for user.
I wanted to also keep list of group invitations on the group document itself (because I know that the number of invitations will be small - lets say less then 50 total) But I am not thinking about dropping this. still The Q remains if I have no way to escape the "dot " to work in update as intended.

Answer (score 0):

As Dror mentioned, adding users with update() and a dot in the key won't work.

I use the set method with merge true:

```
addUserToGroup(id,email,type){
    this.log("id",id,"email",email,"type",type);
    let obj = {};
    obj[email] = type;
    this.angularFireStore.collection("Users").doc(id).set(obj, { merge: true }).then(() => {
      this.log("addedUser",email);
    }).catch((error) => {
      this.log("failed to add user",error)
    })
}
```

From the documentation: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#web-v8_1

"To create or overwrite a single document, use the set() method"

"If you're not sure whether the document exists, pass the option to merge the new data with any existing document to avoid overwriting entire documents."